# ETH p2p node connection using socket Python

Tags: node-discovery, p2p

i trying to set connection with ETH node using devp2p, sockets and Python as a programming language. Every time i send request to node, i always receive empty byte string. What can i do to have positive response?
I tried using 'hello', 'ping', 'status' messages but no result at all.